# How to have a dynamic keyboard in telegram bot

Tags: json, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraf

I am writing a telegram bot with [telegraf](http://telegraf.js.org/#/).
I have a json obj like RSP. it is something like this:

```
[{"captoin", "A"},
 {"caption", "B"},
 {"caption", "C"}]
```

the number of objects in RSP and the values of them("A", "B",...) are not constant and I get them with calling an API.
Now I want to make an inline keyboard for my bot which it's buttons are the values of this json ("A", "B", "C",...).

Thanks for any help.